# What is the proper way of combining existing ASP.NET Core MVC project and React?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC project and I would like to replace view layer (which is html+js atm) with a React app. I've read other similar questions but still don't understand it fully.

I assume that I have to derive my controllers from `ControllerBase` in order to make them behave like API endpoints which React can utilize. Is that correct, or do I have to build a separate REST API on top of existing controllers?

Comment: Just create separate web app for frontend app written in React. And consume your API from React (with React Query or simple `fetch`).

Comment: No need for a separate web app.

Comment: MVC and WebAPI controllers can easily coexist in the very same app. Also, one of your MVC controllers can return the page containing your React frontend.